# What's the standard way of specifying time in an .ics file so that Google preview picks it up correctly?

Tags: datetime, gmail, google-calendar-api, icalendar

When a mail in which a `.ics` file is attached is opened using Gmail, it shows a preview of the event time. That preview is mostly appearing correctly, but occasionally, it shows the time **advanced by 5:30 hours** (Indian Standard Time). At other times, while the preview is wrong, when we proceed to add the event to our calendar, it shows the correct time.

This inconsistency might mean that I'm using a time format which is not officially supported by **ICS** standard (or Gmail).

This is my file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
PRODID://<Org. Name>/<Event Name>//EN
UID:<something>
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20190622T090000+05:30
DTEND:20190622T120000+05:30
SUMMARY:<Summary>
ORGANIZER;CN=<Org. Name>:<Org. EmailID>
LOCATION:<Location>
DESCRIPTION:<Text>
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Some have suggested that we use an Olson identifier like this:

```
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Kolkata:20140606T180000
DTSTART;TZID=US-Pacific:20140606T170000
```

But what is the official way to specify time in an `ics` file so that **Google preview and calendar** reads it correctly? Should I be specifying the time in **GMT** instead? (I think it shouldn't make a difference)

And what is wrong with the style I have used (`20190622T090000+05:30`)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to follow the standard directives of ical. With that, you are sure that it will work with google:

https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-2-19-time-zone-identifier.html

For this case, I suggest you the Olson identifier as yourself suggested.

```
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:19980119T020000
```